# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined, reactjs in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am new in typescript and reactjs, so i need your help to solve this problem. first 2 blocks of code are in QuestionCard.tsx file and that's being rendered in app.tsx file.
I am building a quiz app from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F2JCjVSZlG0&t=34s
My code is here when I run start button function.

```
 17 |     Question: { questionNumber }/{ totalQuestions }
  18 | </p>
  19 | <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: question }} />
> 20 | <div>{answers.map(answer => (
     | ^  21 |     <div key={answer}>
  22 |         <button disabled={ userAnswer } value={ answer } onClick={ callback }>
  23 |             <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: answer }} />
```

this abpve code belongs to this:

```
import React from 'react';

type Props = {
    question: string;
    answers: string[];
    callback: any;
    userAnswer: any;
    questionNumber: number;
    totalQuestions: number;
}

const QuestionCard: React.FC<Props> = ({
    question, answers, callback, userAnswer, questionNumber, totalQuestions,
}) => (
    <div>
        <p className="number">
            Question: { questionNumber }/{ totalQuestions }
        </p>
        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: question }} />
        <div>{answers.map(answer => (
            <div key={answer}>
                <button disabled={ userAnswer } value={ answer } onClick={ callback }>
                    <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: answer }} />
                </button>
            </div>
        ))}
        </div>

    </div>
);

export default QuestionCard;
```

also my browser shows this below code as error:

```
  35 |   setScore(0);
  36 |   setUserAnswers([]);
  37 |   setNumber(0);
> 38 |   setLoading(false);
     | ^  39 | 
  40 | }
  41 |
```

which belongs to this code:

```
    
    setLoading(true);
    setGameOver(false);

    const newQuestions = await fetchQuizQuestions(
      TOTAL_QUESTIONS, 
      Difficulty.EASY
    );

    setQuestions(newQuestions);
    setScore(0);
    setUserAnswers([]);
    setNumber(0);
    setLoading(false);

  }
```

------EDIT------
here below the app.tsx file's code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import QuestionCard from './components/QuestionCard';
import { fetchQuizQuestions } from './API';
import { QuestionState, Difficulty } from './API';

type  AnswerObject = {
  question: string;
  answer: string;
  correct: boolean;
  correctAnswer: string;
}

const TOTAL_QUESTIONS = 10;

const App = () => {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState<QuestionState[]>([]);
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  const [userAnswers, setUserAnswers] = useState<AnswerObject[]>([]);
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const [gameOver, setGameOver] = useState(true);

  const startTrivia = async() => {
    
    setLoading(true);
    setGameOver(false);

    const newQuestions = await fetchQuizQuestions(
      TOTAL_QUESTIONS, 
      Difficulty.EASY
    );

    setQuestions(newQuestions);
    setScore(0);
    setUserAnswers([]);
    setNumber(0);
    setLoading(false);

  }

  const checkAnswer = (e:React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    if(!gameOver) {
      const answer = e.currentTarget.value;
      const correct = questions[number].correct_answer === answer;
      if (correct) setScore(prev => prev + 1);
      const answerObject = {
        question: questions[number].question,
        answer, 
        correct, 
        correctAnswer: questions[number].correct_answer,
      };
      setUserAnswers((prev) => [...prev, answerObject]);
    }
  };

  const nextQuestion = () => {
    const nextQuestion = number + 1;
    if(nextQuestion === TOTAL_QUESTIONS) {
      setGameOver(true);
    } else {
      setNumber(nextQuestion);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React Quiz</h1>
      { gameOver || userAnswers.length===TOTAL_QUESTIONS ? (
          <button className="start" onClick={startTrivia}>Start</button>
      ) : null }
      { !gameOver ? <p className="score">Score: </p> : null }
      { loading && <p>Loading Questions ...</p> }
      { !loading && !gameOver && (
        <QuestionCard 
          questionNumber={number + 1}
          totalQuestions={TOTAL_QUESTIONS}
          question={questions[number].question}
          answers={questions[number].answers}
          userAnswer={userAnswers ? userAnswers[number] : undefined}
          callback={checkAnswer}
        />
      )}
      { !gameOver && !loading && userAnswers.length === number+1 && 
        number !== TOTAL_QUESTIONS - 1 ? (
        <button className="next" onClick={nextQuestion}>Next Question</button>
      ) : null }
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: What is the parent of QuestionCard? Is that the code you have shown, then add more of it.

Comment: @TusharShahi QuestionCard.tsx is located in './components/QuestionCard.tsx' folder, and the second block of code here is all of its code.

Comment: Apologies. Let me rephrase it. Which component is calling QuestionCard. Where is it rendered?

Comment: What is rendering `QuestionCard` component and what are the values of the `answers` prop that is passed to it. It seems that during at least one render it isn't an array, likely the initial render.

Comment: @TusharShahi that's app.tsx file, I imported QuestionCard there

Comment: Add it in the question please. Saves someones time who joins in later.

Comment: @TusharShahi in the second block of the code above in the Props, I declared `answers` as a array

Comment: @TusharShahi okay!

Comment: Declaring something an array type doesn't mean it exists. Where are you defining a value for `answers` before it's passed as a prop to `QuestionCard`? What is its initial state value?

Comment: @DrewReese I edited the post can u check the code again please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers are a required field, It'll be showing waring in the console. For safer side you can add default value,

```
const QuestionCard: React.FC<Props> = ({
  question,
  answers =[], // add this
  callback,
  userAnswer,
  questionNumber,
  totalQuestions,
}) => (
  <div>
    <p className="number">
      Question: {questionNumber}/{totalQuestions}
    </p>
    <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: question }} />
    <div>
      {answers.map((answer) => (
        <div key={answer}>
          <button disabled={userAnswer} value={answer} onClick={callback}>
            <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: answer }} />
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```